# Can anyone decipher this kernel segfault report?

Tags: kernel, bluefish

I use bluefish a lot for coding etc but at the moment it is just closing. I have extracted the following from the logs. Does it mean anything to anyone?

```
 May 26 15:26:39 villa kernel: [  247.521915] bluefish[2262]: segfault at 198 ip 00007f9c2b4376e1 sp 00007fff7c233630 error 4 in libgtk-3.so.0.1000.8[7f9c2b2e1000+4ff000]
```

Comment: Is there an Apport window that comes up, or something about "Sorry, bluefish crashed"?

Comment: nope, it just vanishes

Comment: If [askb's answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/473724/44179) doesn't fix your issue it looks like a bug that needs to be reported to the bluefish developers. See [How do I report a bug?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug) Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The program is hitting a segmentation fault in `libgtk-3.so` which is possibly caused due to accessing a memory segment which the program does not have correct permissions or access to. Check if all the dependencies are updated and correct. Sometimes using a wrong version of the library could cause similar issues.

Next check the output of `ulimit -c`, if this is set to 0 then you won't get a core dump instead you will have to set `ulimit -c unlimited` in your `~/.profile`.

Once you get the core file you could possibly submit the application crash report and the core file.